# Playa not displaying assigned entries

Tags: channel-entries, playa

I have added Playa field to the channel and then assigned entries from another channel to an entry which contains Playa field, but I'm not getting anything from Playa tag.

Code:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="collection" category="84" url_title="{segment_3}" status="open"}
    {title}<br>
    {collection_description}<br>
    Collection contains:
    <ol>
    {collection_products_list}
    <li>{title}</li>
    {/collection_products_list}
    </ol>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

For me it looks like `{collection_products_list}` playa tag is not parsed. Any clue?

Thanks

Comment: Is the status of the related entries in {collection_products_list} 'open'? Are you getting any output at all (like the <li></li> tags) or nothing?

Comment: Not at all. Looks like Playa tags are not "active". Will dig deeper to find out what is going on there because on another site it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found what was causing issue - custom status of selected entries in the Playa field. Those color dots near entries titles there are representing statuses (green - open, red - close, other colors - custom statuses).

In that case I have included custom statuses to the Playa tag.

Answer (score 1):

If you have custom statuses, and you want to show everything, it will help you to get into the habit of using status="not closed". You could even create a global variable for the default status parameter to use.